# Finding Areas in triangles using ratios

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

What theorem/theorems should be used to find the shaded area?

Y and M lie on the sides Ab and Bc respectively of the triangle YMB such that AY/MI= 1/4 and O/M = 1/3.

Area ABC=35
PC and QA intersect at X

Comment: Please do re-post the figure with letters on the vertices/intersection points of segments...and include the explicit info on the areas/sides given.

Comment: You need the ratio of the split on the right side (and the left, which seems to be given). After that, it's just using the proportion of areas.

Comment: What you need is this: Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be triangles with the same height. Then the ratio of their areas is the same as the ratio of their bases.

Comment: @DonAntonio I have added the details

Comment: Sorry @Berry, I can't see how to do it. Either I'm missing something basic or some other data is missing (like similarity between some little triangles or the like...)